# How can you get MediaStore metadata from a DocumentsContract.Document?

Tags: android, uri, mediametadataretriever

My goal is to be able to get a user picked directory using `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and then to get all the audio files and their metadata from that directory. I can already get a user picked directory using `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, but I am unable to extract the audio file metadata. I get null instead of the metadata. I believe the problem is that the Uri returned to `onActivityResult`'s `Intent` is incompatible with the MediaStore Uri.

I can currently get metadata from the MediaStore using the following code:

```
    void getAudioFiles(){
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
        };
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"0"};
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
        try (Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)) {
            if (cursor != null) {
                List<Uri> newURIs = getURIs(cursor);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Uri> getURIs(Cursor cursor) {
        ArrayList<Uri> newURIs = new ArrayList<>();
        int idCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int titleCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int artistCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int dataCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long id = cursor.getLong(idCol);
            String displayName = cursor.getString(nameCol);
            String title = cursor.getString(titleCol);
            String artist = cursor.getString(artistCol);
            String data = cursor.getString(dataCol);
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
            if (!uriMap.containsKey(uri)) {
                AudioURI audioURI = new AudioURI(uri, data, displayName, artist, title, id);
                uriMap.put(uri, audioURI);
            }
            newURIs.add(uri);
        }
        return newURIs;
    }
```

Here I query for `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`. This leads me to believe I need a way to select from the MediaStore based on the Uri returned by `onActivityResult`'s `Intent`

Here is my 1st attempt at trying to get the metadata using the user picked directory.

1st I set an onClickListener to ask the user to pick a directory:

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                String title = getResources().getString(R.string.pick_folder);
                Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
                if (intent.resolveActivity(activityMain.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(chooser, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_FOLDER);
                }
            }
```

Then I get the result and attempt to parse the data:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                 Intent resultData) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_FOLDER && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = null;
            if (resultData != null) {
                uri = resultData.getData();
                final int takeFlags = resultData.getFlags()
                        & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                ContentResolver contentResolver = activityMain.getContentResolver();
                contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
                traverseDirectoryEntries(uri);
            }
        }
    }

    void traverseDirectoryEntries(Uri rootUri) {
        Uri childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(
                rootUri, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(rootUri));
        getFiles(childrenUri, rootUri);
    }

    private void getFiles(Uri childrenUri, Uri rootUri) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = activityMain.getContentResolver();
        List<TreeViewNode> treeViewNodes = new LinkedList<>();
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != ? OR" +
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE + " == ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"0"}, DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR};
        try (Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(childrenUri, new String[]{
                        DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID,
                        DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,
                        DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA},
                selection, selectionArgs, null)) {
            if (cursor != null) {
                int idCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                int nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int titleCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                int artistCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                int dataCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String docId = cursor.getString(0);
                    String name = cursor.getString(1);
                    String mime = cursor.getString(2);
                    long id = cursor.getLong(idCol);
                    this.uriID = id;
                    String displayName = cursor.getString(nameCol);
                    String title = cursor.getString(titleCol);
                    String artist = cursor.getString(artistCol);
                    String data = cursor.getString(dataCol);
                    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
                    if (isDirectory(mime)) {
                        Uri newNode = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(
                                rootUri, docId);
                        getFiles(newNode, rootUri);
                    } else {
                        audioFiles.add(childrenUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isDirectory(String mimeType) {
        return DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR.equals(mimeType);
    }
```

This works fine for finding the files, but not getting the metadata. Every `MediaStore.Audio.Media` column has a null value.

For my 2nd attempt, I tried to use a `MediaMetadataRetriever`, but I get "java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000":

```
        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever;
        mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(activityMain.getApplicationContext(), childrenUri);
```

I think this might be a security problem because the MediaMetadataRetriever does not have the root uri with the read permission. This is because the same files retrieved from the MediaStore Uri are compatible with MediaMetadataRetriever.

For my 3rd try I try to select from the MediaStore based on the document id returned by `onActivityResult`'s `Intent`, but I get a "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: document_id (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)":

```
        ContentResolver contentResolver = activityMain.getContentResolver();
        String selection = DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID + " == ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{docID};
        try (Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
                },
                selection, selectionArgs, null)) {
            if (cursor != null) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    int idCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                    int nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    int titleCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                    int artistCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                    int dataCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                    long id = cursor.getLong(idCol);
                    this.uriID = id;
                    String displayName = cursor.getString(nameCol);
                    String title = cursor.getString(titleCol);
                    String artist = cursor.getString(artistCol);
                    String data = cursor.getString(dataCol);
                    Uri uri1 = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
                }
            }
        }
```

How is one supposed to get audio file meta data from a user picked directory?

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` You cannot grant anything here. Remove that statement. It does nothing. Didnt i say so before?

Comment: You can try [`getMediaUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/MediaStore?hl=en#getmediauri).

Comment: That might work, but it requires Q and I am going for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE gives you a SAF uri from a different provider then the mediastore.

It makes no sense to query the mediastore with a saf uri.

On latests Androids you can convert some saf uries to mediastore uries. And vice versa.

Then use the mediastore urie for querying the mediastore.

Comment: I want to support older version of Android though.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to solve this:

```
    private void getAudioUri(String displayName) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = activityMain.getContentResolver();
        String selection =  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " == ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{displayName};
        try (Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
                },
                selection, selectionArgs, null)) {
            if (cursor != null) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    int idCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                    int nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    int titleCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                    int artistCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                    int dataCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                    long id = cursor.getLong(idCol);
                    this.mediaStoreUriID = id;
                    String displayName2 = cursor.getString(nameCol);
                    String title = cursor.getString(titleCol);
                    String artist = cursor.getString(artistCol);
                    String data = cursor.getString(dataCol);
                    Uri uri1 = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In this case the displayName passed in is from the `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME` column of the document. For some reason, that meta data is available from the Uri retreived from the Intent.

I am not entirely sure if the documents have a "MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME" all the time. This is working on Android Pie and Marshmellow though.